# laplace transform,final value theorem question

Tags: laplace-transform

So I had this question:

> Find the Laplace transforms of the function $
> x(t)=[t \sin(2t) +e^{-2t}]u(t)$. The function $u(t)$ is the unit step function. Check if the initial value theorem and the final value theorem are applicable in each case.

To answer this question I found the Laplace transform using partial fraction which resulted in
$\displaystyle X(S)=\frac{4s}{(4+s^2)^2}+\frac{1}{s+2}$

There's three poles $s=-2, 2i,-2i$. Since its a causal signal
ROC must be $\operatorname{Re}{s}>0$.

For the initial value theorem i used the formula and got 1.

So my question is about the final Value theorem.

When I used the formula of the final value theorem it gives me a value of 0 for $x(\infty)$. However, when I sketched the initial function unto graphing tool (DESMOS), the values is increasingly oscillating in negative and positive values as it reaches infinity. So I'm not sure if it even applicable.

According to my textbook, to apply FVT,  when $t<0$ then $f(t)=0$.

Final value theorem: A signal for which $sX (s)$ is analytic for all $s$ on the
imaginary axis and the right half plane

Correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

As I see it, they seem to be respecting both those conditions, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: The $e^{-2t}$ part of the function seems to behave as expected: $s\frac{1}{s+2}\to 0$ as $s\to 0$ and $e^{-2t}\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$. So probably one should focus on the $t\sin (2t)$ portion which produces the oscillatory divergence.

Comment: Also, if $X(s)$ has poles at $s=\pm2i$, then $sX(s)$ isn't analytic at $s=\pm2i$, and therefore not analytic on the entire imaginary axis.

Comment: Both limits must exist for the theorem to hold. Example with sin(x) which does not have the limit an infinity you may find here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem

Comment: In the case of the Initial value theorem you get limit f(t=0) at t->+0, which is equal 1. The theorem is also not applicable, if we define f(0)=0 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Given that
$$
X(s) = {4 s \over (s^2 + 4)^2} + {1 \over s+2}
$$

The Final Value Theorem (FVT) states that
$$
x(\infty) = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} x(t) = \lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 0} \ [ s X(s) ] \tag{1}
$$
when $s X(s)$ has no poles on the Closed Right-Half Plane, i.e. in the region, where $\mbox{Re}[s] \geq 0$.

For the given problem,
$$
s X(s) = {4 s^2 \over (s^2 + 4)^2} + {s \over s+2} =
{ 4 s^2 (s + 2) + s (s^2 + 4)^2 \over (s + 2) (s^2 + 4)^2}
$$
which has the poles $s = -2, \pm 2 j, \pm 2 j$.

Since $s X(s)$ has four poles on the imaginary axis, we cannot apply Final Value Theorem to deduce the value of $f(\infty)$.